# I am using guid as session id for my web application, is it secure

Tags: security, random, guid, sessionid

I am using guid as session id for my web application, is it secure.

GUID v4.

In security context, is it safe?
If not, what is the reason.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's more fitting on https://security.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I found this [How are .NET 4 GUIDs generated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757910/how-are-net-4-guids-generated). It seems this is vulnerable for collision attacks such as the birthday attack.

Answer (score 0):

Guids are guaranted to be unique. But they are not random. If you generate many guids quickly, you'll see that some of the digits repeat. It's not as secure as a cryptographic random number, but more secure than an integer (especially a database auto-number integer).