# is .net Guid guranteed to be unique when called within a tick?

Tags: guid

There are 10,000 ticks in a millisecond.
one of answers in [How does C# generate GUIDs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888254/how-does-c-sharp-generate-guids) mentions that there are "emergency uniquifier bits" but I don't know enough about that to really tell if I call Guid.GetNext() at tick 1 and 2, I get different GUID.

Comment: Do you really have a scenario where you will be generating guids that fast?

Comment: not within one thread but in multi-threaded environment

Comment: How fast are your computers? It doesn't matter how many threads you have if your computer can't run that fast.

Comment: I have 2 threads that calls GUID at the same time or only by a couple of ticks. does that answer your question?

Comment: Yeah, it does. I wouldn't worry about it. Microsoft probably thought of that one.